# Laravel - Error 405 when testing API, but not when calling from postman

Tags: laravel, http-headers

I'm trying to use the `update` action from some controller in my API. It uses the `PUT` http method. In postman, it works fine, returning a status 200 and my Json response, as expected:

[image]

When I write a Laravel automated test, the same request returns a 405 (Method Not Allowed) error. I tried `dumpHeaders` and discovered the `Allow` header doesn't accept `PUT` requests:

[image]

But the `PUT` endpoint is correctly defined, and working in my local host (see postman request above). Other people seems to have similar problems, but I found no response.

**EDIT:** Here are my api routes (/routes/api.php):

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

// Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
//     return $request->user();
// });

Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('apiLogin');
// Route::post("/register", [AuthController::class, "register"]);

Route::middleware('jwt.verify')->group(function ($router) {
    // Route::post("/logout", [AuthController::class, "logout"]);
    Route::post('/refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
    Route::get('/user-profile', [AuthController::class, 'userProfile']);

    Route::apiResources([
        [...other routes identical to the following...]
        'eselo-comarcas' => EseloComarcasController::class,
        [...other routes identical to the previous...]
    ]);
}
```

**The only thing I can imagine is there is some configuration on accepted Http request methods which is different in local host development environment and in test/production environment.** Can somebody help me?

Comment: can you show us your `route.php`  code please?

Comment: Just put it there. It is in the /routes/api.php.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez HTML form (I think it relates to your TestCase) does not actually have PUT method. Laravel spoofs it with hidden field. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

Fix your test case code to spoof PUT

Comment: Guys, thanks for your time! The problem was my home Internet provider was enduring some instabilities, then I was testing in some previous git version of the application in one of my machines, which indeed didn't had the routes.